# Executing custom redis commands from redis-py

Tags: redis, redis-py

I used [Dynamic Redis](https://matt.sh/dynamic-redis) to add additional functionality to redis. I'm able to use the commands from the redis-cli. Is it possible to use redis-py to use those new commands in a python script ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Found the answer. Just extend one of the client classes(StrictRedis or Redis) and use their execute_command method.

```
redis_client = redis.StrictRedis(host, port, db)
data = redis_client.execute_command('custom redis command')
```

https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/issues/632

Comment: Now StrictRedis and Redis are _same_.